# Finding a linked list neighbor rolling density

Tags: c#, linked-list

I have a linked list like this:

```
public class Node {
    public Node next;
    public Node prev;
    public int length;
    public int weight;
}
```

I am trying to finding a rolling density for a non-circular linked list (has a clear begin and end) that uses a specific length as the window. This adds complexity because the end nodes will only use a percentage of the weight.

That means given 3 nodes

```
A (L: 10, W:10) -> B (L: 5, W:10) -> C (L:20, W:5)
```

(where L means length and W means weight)

and a window of `9` for the node `B`  it would take use all of Node B, and now it has a window of 4 left over. It would evenly split the window before and after so 2 from A and 2 of C.

so the density would be:

```
[(2/10)*(10) + (5/5)*(10) + (2/20)*(5)] / 9 = 1.3889
```

This common case is not the part I am struggling with, its the end point when there is not enough on the left side, the window should take more from the right side and vice versa. There is also the case where there could not be enough length on either side.

I am un-sure if I should implement as a recursive function or a loop. I know a loop would require less calculations but a recursive function could be easier to understand.

Case 1:  There is just 1 node in the linked list
take the density of the 1 node ignoring the window

Case 2:  There is not enough length on the left/right side
Take the remainder from the right/left side.

Case 3:  There is not enough length on both sides, but there is more than just 1 node.
Take all nodes and not require the window to be met.

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "a loop would require less calculations"?

Comment: If doing each node individually you would accessing/calculating things more than once.  A common use-case would be the window would include 100 nodes. You calculate a node (X) and it goes 50 nodes left (X-50), 50 node right (X+50)...then you move on to the next node (X+1) and it does 50 nodes left (X-49) and 50 nodes right (X+51)

all the nodes  X-49 thru X+50 were calculated twice

Comment: If the window size is less than a length of a given node, does it ignore the "remainder" weight values of that node? Perhaps post the function signature of the parent rolling window function?

Comment: No,  if it the current node is larger than the window, it will use the full node and completely ignore the window. That logic is only for the node whos being processed, the seed to the recursive function

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are actually calculating here. Can you explain your example? You had 3 nodes and a window of 9, so I would have thought you needed 9 nodes. It would probably help if you added the code you have (for the common case that you are no struggling with) to calculate this.

Comment: @Matt the window is 9 in length, not 9 nodes. You have to go into each node and see what it's length is and take some % of its weight. For example Node A has a length of 2 taken from it so 2/10 is 20%, we took 20% of its weight.

Comment: @CuriousDeveloper: Okay - that was totally not at all clear.

Comment: *There is also the case where there could not be enough length on either side.* and what should happen in that case? You need to start by defining all the cases and the expected behavior

Comment: I added cases to the question that might help

Answer (score 0):

With all you wrote, it seems your only question is: "should I loop or should I recurse?"  Depending on your needs, whichever is easiest to read and maintain (or if performance is your highest priority, whichever is more performant).

You're dealing with a linked list.  I would recommend simply looping, rather than recursing.  (If you were dealing with a tree, that would be a different story.)  In either case, you may find a way to save a lot of computation by doing some form of memoization.  If your window involves going through hundreds of nodes to the left and right, you can store much of your density calculation for node *n*, and it will almost all be reusable for *n+1*.  Before you get into that, I'd test the non-memoized version first, and see if it's sufficiently performant.

One design pattern that might help you remove your number of edge cases is to have a Null node:

```
Node nullNodeBeginning = new nullNode(length=0, weight=0);
nullNodeBeginning.prev = nullNodeBeginning;
Node nullNodeEnding = new nullNode(length=0, weight=0);
nullNodeEnding.next = nullNodeEnding;
```

If you add `nullNodeBeginning` to the beginning of your linked list and `nullNodeEnding` to the ending of your linked list, you effectively have an infinite linked list.  Then your logic becomes something like:

1. Get the length of the specific center node
2. For previous, next:

   1. Get the length of *n* nodes in that direction (may total to 0)
   2. If total length = total length of list, you can't fill the window
   3. If length < *n*, get nodes from the other direction

There are other ways to do it (and this one requires maintaining the length of all the nodes), but by capping your list with a nullNode, you should be able to avoid all special cases other than "insufficient nodes for the window", and make your logic much cleaner.

Comment: I think the idea of having a self loop at the end is a good idea but I am not following your logic well.

In the example of my original question I would first get center node length (5) Then if I am processing the next i get the length of n nodes. What is n? I don't know how many nodes ill need. Is n the total number of nodes in this link?

Then if this directions total length = the full length, cant fill window. I dont understand why the window can't be filled?